# Error running kitchen_sink.py after installing kivyMD (kivy material design)

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My problem is on the title 
I have installed kivy-garden and kivy and recycleview using theses commands:

pip install kivy-garden
garden install recycleview

Thanks for your help !

Here's the TraceBack :

```
    [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\ouifa\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-06-17_1.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket
[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO              ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.4.0 - Build 10.18.15.4279'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 520'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 4
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.40 - Build 10.18.15.4279'>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] fragment shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO              ] [Shader      ] vertex shader: <b"WARNING: 0:6: '' :  #version directive missing">
[INFO              ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\ouifa\Desktop\KivyMD-master-287939089331bd9c6570fdeaa482901c679c85b8\kitchen_sink.py", line 15, in <module>
     from kivymd.dialog import MDDialog
   File "C:\Users\ouifa\Desktop\KivyMD-master-287939089331bd9c6570fdeaa482901c679c85b8\kivymd\dialog.py", line 8, in <module>
     from theming import ThemableBehavior
 ImportError: No module named 'theming'
```

Comment: It probably has a problem with python 3. Try using python 2 or change import path in that file to `from .theming import ThemableBehavior`.

Comment: I can run kitchen_sink.py with Python 3, so at least now that works. I thought KivyMD is unrelated to Kivy garden? Now there is no `ThemableBehavior` in kitchen_sink.py (anymore?). Are you not looking for: `from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager`?

Answer (score 0):

**[KivyMD](https://github.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD) 0.102.1** has no such error.

Update package via pip and try again.

```sh
python3 -m pip install kivymd
```